# hyperlink in a item template inside the gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have this hyperlink in a item template inside the gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField Headertext ="SN0">
        <ItemTemplate>


       <asp:Hyperlink runat= "server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Container.DataItemIndex + 1")%>' 
                          NavigateUrl='<%# "ResolveComplaint.aspx?Name=" & DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"ComplaintProfileId").tostring & _  
                          "&Status=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Status").tostusring %>' ID="Hyperlink2"/>   
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Basically, I am trying to make the first column(SN0) in a gridview. On click on the hyperlink, it redirects to another Page. I am carrying ComplaintProfileId, Status fields 
to the next page
This gives me a compiletime error:
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Thanks
Sun

Comment: You are doing in c# or vb.net ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you are trying to set the `NavigateUrl` property. You are using the `&` for concatenation, but you have to use the `+ sign` for that. e.g.

```
 NavigateUrl='<%# "ResolveComplaint.aspx?Name=" + DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"ComplaintProfileId").tostring +  
                      "&Status=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Status").tostusring %>'
```

Comment: I am using C#. In the Text property: How should I generate a serial number

Comment: Text='<%# Eval("SerialNumber")%>'

Answer (score 0):

Should your .tostring and tostusring calls be .ToString()?